# How to bind data from database to a specific DatagridView Column Name using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to bind different queries for a long set of columns in datagridview that has been set already during the formload, e.g:

With dgvGrid

```
.Columns(0).Name = "Dept Code"
        .Columns(1).Name = "Emp ID"
        .Columns(2).Name = "Pay Date"
        .Columns(3).Name = "Pay Type"
        .Columns(4).Name = "Regular Days"
        .Columns(5).Name = "Holidays"
        .Columns(6).Name = "Tardy Hours"
        .Columns(7).Name = "Tardy Amount"
        .Columns(8).Name = "Basic Pay"
        .Columns(9).Name = "Regular Wage"
        .Columns(10).Name = "Reg OT Hrs"
        .Columns(11).Name = "Reg OT Amt"
        .Columns(12).Name = "Rest OT Hrs"
        .Columns(13).Name = "Rest OT Amt"
        .Columns(14).Name = "Legal OT Hrs"
        .Columns(15).Name = "Legal OT Amt"
```

there are still more of it. The data needed for those columns is coming from a different table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and you need to make queries on you data exist in the grid view!
The Best way to do is using DataView and bind it to the DataGridView and make your queries using the RowFilter in DataView...

DataView dvTemp = new DataView(dsTemp.Tables[0]);
dataridviewEmployee.DataSource = dvTemp;

On your Query:

dvTemp.RowFilter = "Emp_ID  <= 100  AND   Regular_Wage > 2000";

Comment: Hi Mohammed.. Sorry about my English. Hmmm What i really mean is that.. In my program i loaded 1st the Column Header of my gridview then when i click some button this will now execute different queries going to the database and access different kinds of table and bind each query results to different Columns in my datagridview.

Comment: Hi Mohammed.. Sorry about my English. Hmmm What i really mean is that.. In my program i loaded 1st the Column Header of my gridview then when i click some button this will now execute different queries going to the database and access different kinds of table and bind each query results to different Columns in my datagridview.   Example i have there is "Emp ID" will be fill out with data taken from "Employee table" and .Column(6).Name = "Tardy Hours" will be fill out with data taken from "Daily Attendance table" where Emp ID = to .Column(1).Name = "Emp ID" data.

Comment: Then you should make your select query to combine both tables from DB  and return it as single table. like:
Select emp.ID as 'ID' , emp.col1, emp.col2 , emp.col3 , empDailyAtt.HoursCol 
From emp, empDailyAtt

Comment: Then you should make your select query to combine both tables from DB  and return it as single table. like:
Select emp.ID as 'ID' , emp.col1, emp.col2 , emp.col3 , empDailyAtt.HoursCol 
From emp, empDailyAtt
Where emp.ID = empDailyAtt.ID

Comment: Hmmm i cant since there should be a deduction or adjustment that needs to be trigger by date and by Check Box. Example. This paydate there will be no TAX and There should be and adjustment on salary in a particular paydate. Is there no other way where i can just bind the data in a particular column of my gridview? like the way it works on VB 6 before where you can just trigger it using index or Column name. Thank you.